# Missing some parentehtesis

Tags: oracle

Working on the case statement below and keep getting a missing parenthesis error. any suggestions?

```
( CASE        
  WHEN  XBAND = 4 AND TBAND = 0 AND YBAND >= 2
 THEN 'A'
 END
 ELSE
 CASE
 WHEN  XBAND = 4 AND TBAND = 0 AND YBAND >= 3
 THEN 'B'
 END 
  END ) XYT_BAND
```

Comment: Are you trying to nest those case statements? Or just have a single case statement with 2 cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate multiple rows for each entry you could use `union` or more flexible `unpivot` transposing columns to rows:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/SUOI51451)</sup>**

```
select id, xyt_band
  from (select id, 
               case when xband = 4 and yband = 0 and tband >= 2 then 'A' end c1, 
               case when xband = 4 and yband = 0 and tband >= 3 then 'B' end c2
          from t)
  unpivot (xyt_band for cx in (C1, C2))
```

Comment: What does id represent?

Answer (score 2):

There should only be one `END` per `CASE` expression. This should work:

```
 CASE        
   WHEN  XBAND = 4 AND TBAND = 0 AND YBAND >= 2
     THEN 'A'
   WHEN  XBAND = 4 AND TBAND = 0 AND YBAND >= 3
     THEN 'B'
   END XYT_BAND
```

If you need to nest `CASE` expressions then:

```
 CASE        
   WHEN  XBAND = 4 AND TBAND = 0 AND YBAND >= 2
     THEN 'A'
   ELSE
     CASE
       WHEN  XBAND = 4 AND TBAND = 0 AND YBAND >= 3
       THEN 'B'
     END
   END XYT_BAND
```

Comment: trying to nest them

Comment: Why?  You don't need to for this.

Comment: The results seems to be wrong. I expected to get A and a B since both conditions are true but it appears only returning an A. any suggestions?

Comment: No a `CASE` expression can only return one value.  Not sure what you want really - 2 rows, or a row with 'AB' for XYT_BAND?

Comment: should be a column with two rows for A and a B.

Comment: I'm not even sure what "a column with 2 rows" means!  "A row with 2 columns" I can understand...  Maybe you need to ask a new question, showing what data you have and what you want the SQL to show.

Comment: Prod id XYT_BAND
1             A
  2            B

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. basically its XYT_BAND is a column and the results of the case statement should be in that column as  A for one row and B for another row

Comment: CASE does not generate rows, it generates a column value for 1 row.

Comment: Can i use the above query then to generate two column values ?

Comment: No, try Ponder Stibbons's answer.